# How to round time to the nearest previous quarter hour in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

I want round time to the nearest previous quarter hour in Groovy

Example :
Current Date : 2023-01-15T06:15:51
Expected Output (DateTime rounded to previous quarter) : 2023-01-15T06:15:00

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit

LocalDateTime CurrentDTM = LocalDateTime.now()
println(CurrentDTM)

LocalDateTime lastQuarter = CurrentDTM.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.HOURS)
                                .plusMinutes(15 * ((CurrentDTM.getMinute() / 15).intValue()))
println(lastQuarter)
```